# External hard drive no filesystem

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Suddenly my laptop can't detect my external hard drive.
I've read similar situations somewhere and based on what I've understand, my ext disk is not mounted but when I try to mount it some error occurs. Maybe because there is no filesystem currently in this hard drive.

Previously, when it was running its filesystem was fuse. And it was doing fine back then. It lasts for about 2 years before I encountered this issue.

[Details from Disk GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxdNu.png)

I am totally new to ubuntu. I'm hoping someone can guide me. There are some important files on this disk so I can't afford to lose those files.

Comment: "I try to mount it some error occurs" and we are suppose to guess the error? Please edit into the question command and result otherwise there is nothing to go on. "There are some important files on this disk so I can't afford to lose those files."  Why is this a issue? Since you call it "important files" you will have multiple backups.

Comment: If using fuse, it was FAT32 or NTFS? Often then it is a Windows issue that you cannot fix from Linux.  Did you plug into a Windows system so that now Windows hibernation flag is set? Or does it need chkdsk which only can be run from Windows. Or possibly a BS - Boot Sector issue. You want to get to this screen:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery

Comment: @oldfred yes, I forgot to mention that I tried to plug it in a windows system, I was trying to recover some files that doesn't show in my folder and I was gonna try to use chkdisk to recover it [see this link ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4e2HcLvSC8). I wasn't able to see the ext hard drive in windows since then the issue started to occur.

Comment: @Rinzwind as u can see, someone can guess well xD